# Haman and God sleeping

Tags: sources-mekorot, megillat-esther, sleep, haman

Is there a source for Haman claiming that God is "sleeping" during the time he wanted to commit the genocide?

Comment: https://he.m.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%90%D7%A1%D7%AA%D7%A8_%D7%A8%D7%91%D7%94_%D7%96_%D7%99%D7%91

Answer (score 2):

Great question. The answer to your question is yes.

This is discussed in Esther Rabbah 7:12, as well as [here](https://www.sefaria.org/Sha%27ar_HaKavanot%2C_Sermons_on_the_Festival_of_Purim.3?vhe=Shaar_HaKavanot&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en#:%7E:text=%D7%94%D7%99%D7%94%20%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A1%D7%98%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%9C%D7%95%D7%92%D7%95%D7%A1%20%D7%92%D7%93%D7%95%D7%9C%20%D7%9B%D7%A0%D7%95%D7%93%D7%A2%20%D7%91%D7%A2%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%9F%20%D7%95%D7%99%D7%A4%D7%9C%20%D7%A4%D7%95%D7%A8%20%D7%94%D7%95%D7%90%20%D7%94%D7%92%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%9C%20%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%95%D7%9D%20%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%95%D7%9D%20%D7%9B%D7%95%27%20%D7%95%D7%91%D7%A4%D7%A8%D7%98%20%D7%91%D7%9E%22%D7%A9%20%D7%91%D7%A1%22%D7%94%20%D7%9B%D7%99%20%D7%94%D7%95%D7%90%20%D7%95%D7%A2%D7%A9%D7%A8%D7%AA%20%D7%91%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%95%20%D7%9B%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%9D%20%D7%9B%D7%9C%20%D7%A2%D7%A9%D7%A8%D7%94%20%D7%A7%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%A4%D7%99%D7%9F%20%D7%94%D7%97%D7%99%D7%A6%D7%95%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%9D%20%D7%95%D7%99%D7%93%D7%A2%20%D7%91%D7%97%D7%9B%D7%9E%D7%AA%D7%95%20%D7%A2%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%9F%20%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%A2%D7%95%D7%98%20%D7%94%D7%A9%D7%92%D7%97%D7%AA%D7%95%20%D7%99%D7%AA%27%20%D7%A2%D7%9C%20%D7%99%D7%A9%D7%A8%D7%90%D7%9C%20%D7%91%D7%99%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%9D%20%D7%94%D7%94%D7%9D%20%D7%9C%D7%94%D7%99%D7%95%D7%AA%D7%95%20%D7%91%D7%91%D7%97%D7%99%27%20%D7%94%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%A0%D7%94%20%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%9B%D7%9F%20%D7%97%D7%A9%D7%91%20%D7%95%D7%A2%D7%9C%D7%94%20%D7%91%D7%9C%D7%91%D7%95%20%D7%9B%D7%99%20%D7%94%D7%96%D7%9E%D7%9F%20%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%9B%D7%9F%20%D7%9C%D7%90%D7%91%D7%93%20%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%A0%D7%90%D7%99%D7%94%D7%9D%20%D7%A9%D7%9C%20%D7%99%D7%A9%D7%A8%D7%90%D7%9C).

I am sure there are other places, but this is a good starting point for you to delve into this deeper.

Comment: See also Perush Maharzu on Esther Rabbah (7:12:2)

Comment: Please consider summarizing your sources, as that would make your answer potentially more valuable.